# Unable to change preferences in Acroread v9.4.2

Tags: adobe, adobe-reader

I can view the preferences but the selection boxes are all locked, as well as the Cancel and OK buttons.  The only option is to close it.

Have tried uninstall/re-install acroread but situation persists.

Is there some system settings that I need to change to unlock preferences?

Comment: Have you tried also removing the `~/.adobe/Acrobat` directory?

Comment: can confirm the issue - and removing .adobe/Acrobat does not resolve.

Comment: I can confirm, too. [So can this.](http://www.ubuntufreunde.de/forum/3877/adobe_reader_9_voreinstellungen_nicht_nutzbar.html)

The proposed chmod solution (see link) does nothing -- which is no surprise, as the preferences can be changed: pressing F7, for example, changes something, but the preferences dialog is inactive.

The guy from the link solved his problem by copying his preferences from his Ubuntu 10.10 installation, if this is any help. It didn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it can be done, if you know how to use the keyboard. It's just the mouse that does not work in the Preferences window. For those who don't, you use tab to move between the sections, spacebar to select or deselect the checkboxes, and press enter a couple of times with the OK button selected.

Hope this helps.